# Can't resolve module nativescript-xmpp-client

Tags: quickblox

I'm trying to use QuickBlox via JavascriptSDK and when I try to use it I have the message:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'nativescript-xmpp-client' in
```

Just followed the small steps on documentation installing via npm

Comment: I'm having the same issue and have not found an answer yet.

Comment: @MarkFreedman after a lot of research my solution was using the cdn link in public/index.html file and use it as global node variable like: const QB = window.QB.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65921718/error-module-not-found-cant-resolve-nativescript-xmpp-client-in-home-rake for a possible solution with different import syntax.