# Error: Module not found: Can't resolve 'nativescript-xmpp-client' in '/home/rakesh95/Projects/webapp/node_modules/quickblox/src/modules/chat'

Tags: reactjs, quickblox

I am trying to use QuickBlox JavaScript SDK for chat communication for react.js app. But while running the app i am getting this error. I have installed all the dependencies but still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Try importing it like so:

```js
import * as QB from 'quickblox/quickblox'
```